# Algorithm for selecting songs for a Playlist

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, search

I need an algorithm to select songs based on times listened, skips and ratings to create a playlist from a big pool of songs.
The playlist should only play songs that are good and that I like and some ones that I don't hear often but are not rated badly. But the playlist shouldn't include songs that I often Skip.

I came up with this formula but it didn't gave me the result I was expecting.

```
score = popularity * ( 1 - skip_freq/max_skips ) * rating
```

Where `popularity` is how often the song got played, `skip_freq` is how often it got skipped, `max_skips` is the total number of skips and the `rating` is a rating between 1 and 5 that is provided by the user.

I would then sort all songs by their score and pick like the top 50 for my list. To add some variation I would add some that are not often played but have a low skip_freq and randomly insert them to get up to 60ish songs.

Is that a valid schema for selecting songs and would that work?

Comment: What exactly is `skip_freq` and `skip_freq`? That equation kind of looks like its choosing mostly songs that you skip often

Comment: `skip_freq` os how often the Song got skiped yet. And I see where you are going with your comment. Would it be smarter to multiply `popularity` with `1 / (skip_freq / max_skips)`? because then the score would get lower if the song is skiped more often

Comment: Is `popularity` the number of times the user played the song? You'll probably have to divide that by the total number of songs played to get anything useful. Also, multiplying by `rating`, a number from 1 to 5, is probably going to favor highly-rated songs that aren't played often or are skipped often over lower-rated songs that you never skip.

Comment: You need to give more thought to how the variables you're using interact with each other, and decide how strongly each should contribute to the final score. For example, do you really want to keep playing songs that you've heard over and over? One thing I found in the past is that `number_of_plays/total_songs_played` quickly results in the same few songs being selected. `log(plays/total_plays)` or `sqrt(plays/total_plays)` (or similar calculations) can help minimize these effects.

Answer (score 1):

A Bernoulli trial is a random experiment with two outcomes, like flipping a coin, or deciding whether to skip a song.

Let's say we're trying to estimate the probability that you'll skip a given song. Each time you begin listening to it, a trial has begun. That trial ends when you either skip or make it to the end of the song.

Then your measured skip rate for a song is (number of skips) / (number of skips + listens)

That measurement is useless unless you have a lot of data on each song. E.g., you wouldn't want to treat a song you started once and skipped to have a 100% bad rating.

The "Wilson score interval" of a Bernoulli trial is the 95% confidence interval around a proportion.

My recommendation is to calculate the lower end of the Wilson score interval, and use that as your probability of skipping.

Here are some sample results:

```
Trials  Skips  Wilson_lower
1       0      0.0
1       1      0.2065
10      1      0.0179 
10      3      0.1078
100     10     0.0552
100     30     0.2189
1000    100    0.0829
1000    300    0.2724
```

If you implement this, you can check your results [here](http://vassarstats.net/prop1.html).

You then use this as your 'badness' score, and select the songs with the lowest score.

Here's a Ruby implementation:

```
def wilson(trials, successes, z=1.96)
  # z = 1.96 chosen for 95% confidence interval
  p = successes.to_f / trials
  denominator = 1 + z**2 / trials
  center_adjusted_probability = p + z**2 / (2*trials)
  adjusted_std_dev = ((p*(1 - p) + z**2 / (4*trials)) / trials)**0.5
    
  lower_bound = (center_adjusted_probability - z*adjusted_std_dev) / denominator
  upper_bound = (center_adjusted_probability + z*adjusted_std_dev) / denominator
  return [lower_bound, upper_bound]
end
```

Comment: We're using the lower end of the interval to give songs the benefit of the doubt until the evidence is strong that they're good. In addition to making playlists, you could build a song-player around this which selects random songs based on the lower end of their score. As you keep skipping a song, it would fade out of rotation, or you could have some threshold at which you never pick a song.